# How to split date and time from string

Tags: r, split

I have this code

```
dtparts<-t(as.data.frame(strsplit(as.character(YOURDATA$datetime),' ')))
row.names(dtparts)=NULL

To make chron object
YOURDATA$dtime<-chron(dates=dtparts[,1], times=dtparts[,2])
```

but when I used in my data, doesn't work, and I don't know why?
 **

```
dtparts<-t(as.data.frame(strsplit(as.character(s1$datetime),' ')))
s1$dtime<-chron(dates=dtparts[,1], times=dtparts[,2])
```

> ```
> Error in convert.dates(dates., format = format[[1]], origin. = origin.) :   
>  format m/d/y may be incorrect Además: Warning message: In
>  convert.dates(dates., format = format[[1]], origin. = origin.) :   NAs
>  introducidos por coerción
> ```

really I don´t know what happend, 
Please someone can help me

Comment: What does the string `YOURDATA$datetime` look like? Please update the problem above.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(YOURDATA$datetime)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(YOURDATA$datetime, 20))`.

Comment: Reading this may help improve the question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: dput(head(s1$datetime, 20))

Comment: Run `dput(head(s1$datetime, 20)) ` in Rstudio and share output of that command. We want to know your data structure. Also you can mention expected output.

Comment: structure(c(16945.5027777778, 16945.5097222222, 16945.5166666667, 
16945.5236111111, 16945.5305555556, 16945.5375, 16945.5444444444, 
16945.5513888889, 16945.5583333333, 16945.5652777778, 16945.5722222222, 
16945.5791666667, 16945.5861111111, 16945.5930555556, 16945.6, 
16945.6069444444, 16945.6138888889, 16945.6208333333, 16945.6277777778, 
16945.6347222222), format = structure(c("m/d/y", "h:m:s"), .Names = c("dates", 
"times")), origin = structure(c(1, 1, 1970), .Names = c("month", 
"day", "year")), class = c("chron", "dates", "times"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution could be to change the `as.character(s1$datetime)` as 
`format(s1$datetime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")` in the 1st line. Hence the 1st line will be as

```
dtparts<-t(as.data.frame(strsplit(format(s1$datetime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"),' ')))
```

The reason is format mismatch for `date` part. The default `date` format for `chron` is `"m/d/y"` and `as.character` produces in `Y-m-d` format. Hence, the mismatch. We have two choices to fix issue:

1. Change the format of string representing `Date` part to match expectation of `chron`. This has been explained above.
2. Specify format for the `Date` part in your function `chron`. This can be achieved by chanding `2nd` line of code as:

   `s1$dtime<-chron(dates=dtparts[,1], times=dtparts[,2], format = c(dates = "y/m/d", times = "h:m:s"))`

Comment: thanks for your answer, your solution was good, now when I run the code the result is not what it should be, that is, two columns one with the name "date" and the other with the name "times", only with the same name as before, what could be?

Comment: @Sofia Good to know that it fixed your problem. If you share part of your data then people can help. `dput(YOURDATA)` and share output as part of your question.